# What technologies to be used in combination with ASP.NET MVC and VS2013 to build a multiplatform responsive web design (RWD)

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I am a .NET desktop app developer and now I need to build a multiplatform web app using ASP.NET MVC (It is a must) from the scratch. I have no experience in web programming, I only have basic knowledge about it.

This web app should be responsive (RWD) and able to work on all type of devices such as mobiles, tablets, desktop computers, laptops, etc. .... and using OSes like Windows, Android, iOS, MacOS, Linux, etc.

So I was thinking to build a web app using BootStrap as responsive framework in combination with ASP.NET MVC in Visual Studio 2013. Am I in the right direction? I have also heard about Foundation. Also, can I combine HTML5, CSS3, BootStrap and ASP.NET MVC using Visual Studio 2013? What I need to do to use HTML5, CSS3 and BootStrap with ASP.NET MVC in Visual Studio 2013? I am a bit lost.

Comment: There's no silver bullet here. You'll need to learn the technologies involved. I must say that using a six-year-old IDE is not a good start.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest for you to use [aspnetboilerplate](https://aspnetboilerplate.com/) as free framework , its ready using MVC 5 or Core, with bootstrap as well as metronic 4, and you have the ability to go with React or angular within same framework,
but you need visual studio 2017